# I have a [slug] file that dont work with tailwind

Tags: next.js, tailwind-css

I am doing my portfolio and i want to have diferents pages for diferents projects, everything works fine i can click on the card and the new page open, but i cant style this new page, here is the code:

```
// pages/projetos/[slug].tsx
import { useRouter } from "next/router"
import { projetosData } from "../../app/projetosdata"

const ProjetoDetalhes = () => {
  const router = useRouter()
  const { slug } = router.query
  const projeto = projetosData.find(
    (p: { id: { toString: () => string | string[] | undefined } }) => p.id.toString() === slug
  )

  if (!projeto) {
    return <div>Projeto não encontrado</div>
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h1 className="text-3xl font-bold underline">Hello world!</h1>
    </div>
  )
}

export default ProjetoDetalhes
```

This part, dont work properly

```
  return (
    <div>
      <h1 className="text-3xl font-bold underline">Hello world!</h1>
    </div>
  )
```

everythink outside this file work with tailwind, also here is my tailwind.config file

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./app/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
    "./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
    "./components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",

    // Or if using `src` directory:
    "./src/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

i try doing some changes on the tailwind.config file, hoping that i am missing some export i dont know